# jenkins is not using local maven repository

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have few jars which I have installed in my local maven repo(in windows under user/.m2). While building the project from command-line it's perfectly downloading the jars and packaging it.

Now I have created a Jenkins job (mvn clean package) to do so, but while running the jobs it's not picking up those jars from local repo instead trying to download it from central repo.

I tried all possible solutions available in Internet but still no luck. Can you please how I can configure Jenkins so that it should download those jars from my local repo ?

I also tried :-
1. offline mode
2. gave local repo path in settings.xml
3. use of nexus/artifactory in not an option for me

Comment: First make the installation of config-file-provider plugin and configure a settings.xml in Jenkins there...configure your job to use the configured settings ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems maven executed by Jenkins not used the `settings.xml` in your local

you can try to change the maven command/goal in Jenkins job configuration with one more option: 
 `-f <your local settings.xml path>`

you can copy the `settings.xml` to your source code folder for debug purpose, after prove it work, then consider how to prepare the `settings.xml` for jenkins job with below options:

**Option 1**  use `Config file provider` plugin 
[image]

Click `Config Files -> Add a New Config -> Maven settings.xml`

Change name and set your xml into content field:

[image]

In your job configuration, click the `Advance...` button in Build Section, choose your added settings.xml as below:

[image]

Comment: do not go this way in Jenkins. There is a config file provider plugin for Jenkins which can handle the settings.xml perfectly...